# jQuery Mobile css and javascript are not linked to my code

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am new to jQuery Mobile and i am trying to implement the sample jQuery Mobile application from a tutorial.

**Here is my code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/> 
            <title>Title</title>  
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/> 

                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile.css" />       
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>           
    </head>  
    <body> 

        <div  data-role="page">                                                       
            <div  data-role="header">                                                 
                <h1>Page Header</h1>  
            </div>  

            <div  data-role="content" >                                                 
                <p>Hello jQuery Mobile!</p>  
            </div>  

            <div  data-role="footer">                                                 
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>  
            </div>  
        </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

All the referenced files are included in my project. But the problem is my output is a simple html page without any js or css rule applied.

I want my output like jQuery Mobile sample app.

Please help me.

Comment: the css and js files should be in the same folder where html file is.

Comment: If you open to view the source of your webpage, it should display the references to the css and jquery files as links. If you click on these, does the browser find them? If not, your href or src is wrong...

Comment: i am doing it in iphone simulator. how can i check its source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use one of the following solutions:

### Solution 1:

This 1st solution consists **in including your jQuery Mobile's CSS / JS files locally** (= in your folder `www`)

**1 -** Include your HTML file `index.html` inside your folder `www`.

**2 -** Dowload the three CSS, JS files from the respective links:

- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css
- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css
- http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js
- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js

**3 -** Copy the CSS files to `www/css/` and the JS files into `www/js/`, while **making sure that the references in XCode are done successfully**.

**You can do the following to achieve the above:**

1. Right click on your folder `www/css/` or `www/js/` in XCode,

   `New File...` -> `iOS` / `Other` -> `Empty` -> `Next`. 

   Then, enter the file to copy (for example: `jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css`).
2. Copy & Paste the content of the file (ex: `jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css`) you downloaded into the new file that you created above, in XCode.
3. Repeat the steps 1 and 2 for all the CSS / JS files you downloaded (`jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css`, `jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css`, `jquery-1.8.1.min.js`, and `jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js`).

Once your files are copied, you should have the following directory structure:

- **www**

  - `index.html`
  - **css**

    - `jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css`
    - `jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css`
  - **js**

    - `jquery-1.8.1.min.js`
    - `http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js`

**4 -** Now, considering the path of your jQuery Mobile's CSS / JS files, you can add their references in the header of your HTML file `index.html`.

**Full example of `index.html`:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="./js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>  
    <body> 

        <div  data-role="page">                                                       
            <div  data-role="header">                                                 
                <h1>Page Header</h1>  
            </div>  

            <div  data-role="content" >                                                 
                <p>Hello jQuery Mobile!</p>  
            </div>  

            <div  data-role="footer">                                                 
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>  
            </div>  
        </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

---

### Solution 2:

This 2nd solution consists in getting the jQuery Mobile's CSS / JS files from the external server at http://code.jquery.com .

The problem with Phonegap is that **you need to add specific whitelist exceptions for allowing the retrieval of external data**.

**For more information about this whitelist, I suggest you to check the online doc** (this one is for Phonegap / Cordova version 2.1, you may check the appropriate link according to your version of Phonegap / Cordova): http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Since you're using XCode (and you're developping for iOS), you have to following these steps in order to add `http://code.jquery.com` to your whitelist exception:

- Open the file `Resources/Cordova.plist` in XCode.
- Right click on the line `ExternalHosts`, and select `Add row`.
- Set the `String` value of the new created line to `code.jquery.com`.
- Save your modified file and close it.

Now, your can include the references of your external CSS / JS files in the header of you HTML `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

**Full example of `index.html`:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    </head>  
    <body> 

        <div  data-role="page">                                                       
            <div  data-role="header">                                                 
                <h1>Page Header</h1>  
            </div>  

            <div  data-role="content" >                                                 
                <p>Hello jQuery Mobile!</p>  
            </div>  

            <div  data-role="footer">                                                 
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>  
            </div>  
        </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your solutions seems to be good. but its really not working for me... again same simple html page. should i send my sample Xcode project to you?

Comment: Ok mate, I've changed my previous post. Have a look and try one of the solutions I posted ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot Littm.. i went for solution 2. and its working now. you are always of great help.Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Have u checked using firebug in firefox to make sure that the actual javascript libraries are getting loaded? Where you are referencing the files, is this pointing to the correct location?

Simple i know, but could have been overlooked :)